# error for tf::TransformListener

Tags: transform-listener, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/linedetect.dir/src/linedetect.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'tf::TransformListener::~TransformListener()'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'tf::TransformListener::~TransformListener()' is defined in DSO /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libtf.so so try adding it to the linker command line
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/libtf.so: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/sihanwan/catkin_ws/devel/lib/lab2/linedetect] Error 1
make[1]: *** [lab2/CMakeFiles/linedetect.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

this is my class

**class Change
{
public:
laser_geometry::LaserProjection projector;

```
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Publisher pub;
    ros::Subscriber sub;
    Change();
    void scanCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& scan_in);
private:
    tf::TransformListener listener;
```

};**

any help appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/155446/error-for-tf::transformlistener/) by [ushergod](https://answers.ros.org/users/15016/ushergod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The following worked for me... I added "tf" to my CMakeLists.txt find_package(). E.g.:

find_package( catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp .... tf)

---

Originally posted by [b3l33](https://answers.ros.org/users/15041/b3l33/) with karma: 113 on 2014-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sina.cb](https://answers.ros.org/users/11966/sina.cb/) on 2014-08-10**:
It worked for me too!
Thanks! :)